# change button's scale and add a shadow when click button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, shadow

[image]

I want to change the button's scale and add a shadow effect when the button is clicked, but the added shadow effect is not complete, where is the problem, why is the shadow of the last button only complete?

[image]

```
 @objc func ButtonOnClicking(_ sender:homePageBtn){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        sender.layer.masksToBounds = false
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
        sender.layer.shadowColor = ColorHellp.getColor("333333").cgColor
        sender.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        sender.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        sender.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3

    }) { (isfinished) in
        print("finished")
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to zoom button  and add shadow from all side when click on button and when you click other button then same process but remove shadow and zoom out previous button. You can get zoom effect by increase scale of button and add shadow by shadowoffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see, that also for the first button the shadow is complete, but it looks like, that the button is under the other ones.

So try something like bringSubViewToFront or change the z-index.

Comment: Thank you, I used bringSubview(toFront:),the shadow shows complete